# Was there a common influence for the characters Leela on Futurama and Aeryn on Farscape

Tags: futurama, inspiration, farscape, female-characters

I recently started watching the series Farscape and something that struck me were the similarities between the character Aeryn and Leela from Futurama, detailed below.

Both shows were made in 1999, so neither one was the guiding influence on the other. Does anyone know of a prior show that may have influenced both characters, or a writer that worked for both shows?

Similarities as I see them

- Cocky, punch/kick first attitude
- Tall, dark haired, always wearing combat boots
- Left their former life and occupation after meeting the shows chief protagonist
- Adds sexual tension to the show with the chief protagonist because they are similar, but not exactly the same, in each case the female is uncertain while the male (Crichton and Fry) are certain

There's much less of a connection between Crichton and Fry, but is seems interesting that Crichton is basically everything Fry wishes he was at the start of Futurama.

Comment: It's a common archetype :)

Comment: Leela from Futurama doesn't have dark hair. Her hair is a light-to-medium purple color.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See TV Tropes' pages on [Action Girl](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ActionGirl) and [Action Girlfriend](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ActionGirlfriend).  The idea of a female character who can kick butt isn't a new one, and in modern sci-fi it's expected that female characters will not be the damsels in distress of the olden days.

Also, this:

- Tall, dark haired, always wearing combat boots

Is basically describing an Amazon.

Comment: I get that, but you are referring to one of the four points made, not all four. If that was the only similarity I would not have asked the question.

Comment: I think all 4 points relate.  Combat boots are a costume accessory that, from a practical standpoint, meshes quite naturally with an "Action Girl" concept.  The personalities implied with the archetype naturally lead to use of the "switching sides" plot hook as a means of introducing them as regular characters.  The sexual tension is similarly an extension of the personality type combined with plot hook, as popular strong, assertive personalities naturally make good love interests that add more complexity than 'yeah, we used to date'.

Comment: Yep.  All the points are related.  Leaving your former life is common to any character, when they get sucked into a new plotline.  points one and 2 are very common to action girls, and point 4 comes up because it's common for action girls, and because ANY male/female duo as main characters will typically get shipped.

Comment: What is meant that a woman who is "Tall dark haired, always wearing combat boots" is descriptive of an Amazon? Amazon as in ancient Greece? They weren't necessarily dark haired nor wearing combat boots. Or an Amazon like on the TV show, Xena? They weren't all dark-haired even though Xena was. Or is Amazon specific to Action Girls, which the answer references? I am not familiar with Action Girls, so I wasn't sure. Just curious, as without specific context, Amazon females in science-fiction are non-specific in appearance.

Answer (score 0):

She is based on the character Leela from Doctor Who, I can't find it now but Matt Groening mentioned it in an interview. She was the companion of the Fourth Doctor. A quick Google should help you find out more.

Comment: As the provider of the answer the onus is on you to include the source. You should do the Google search to find the interview//quote and edit it in.

Comment: Note that this is only half of an answer; you also need to establish Aeryn was _also_ based on Dr. Who's Leela.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Sorry I was on mobile at the time and thought that the information would be welcome. If not then that's fine.

Comment: @DavidW You're right, I added it quickly while on mobile. I should have really just added it as a comment rather than an answer because it doesn't address the question directly.

Comment: @poncho this information is welcome but it would be greatly improved if you add the evidence in. Especially since you know what you’re looking for.